# itertools.product does not gives correct permutation for lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do permutation for some lists. If I perform cartesian product with `itertools.product` function, then the output is really weird for me

If I do permutation for following two lists, which contains strings:

```
list1= ('In1', 'In2')
list2= ('Ta1', 'Ta2')
list3= []
list3Append= []
for list3 in itertools.product(list1, list2, repeat=1):
    list3Append.append(list3)
print('list3Append:\n', list3Append)
```

The output is ok

```
list3Append:[('In1', 'Ta1'), ('In1', 'Ta2'), ('In2', 'Ta1'), ('In2', 'Ta2')]
```

And more two lists, which contains numbers:

```
list4= ([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
list5= ([[7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]])
list6= []
list6Append= []
for list6 in itertools.product(list4, list5, repeat=1):
    list6Append.append(list6)
print('list6Append:\n', list6Append)
```

The output is also ok

```
list6Append:[([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]), ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12])]
```

But if I want to do permutation for `list3Append` and `list6Append`

```
list7= []
for list7 in itertools.product(list3Append, list6Append, repeat=1):
    print('list7:\n', list7)
```

Then I get:

```
list7: (('In1', 'Ta1'), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta1'), ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta1'), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta1'), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta2'), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta2'), ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta2'), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta2'), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta1'), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta1'), ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta1'), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta1'), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta2'), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta2'), ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta2'), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta2'), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]))
```

The correct output should be:

```
list7: (('In1', 'Ta1'), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In1', 'Ta2'), ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta1'), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]))
list7: (('In2', 'Ta2'), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]))
```

What I do wrong here?
Thank you

Comment: Your "correct output" contains e.g. only one line starting with `('In1', 'Ta1')`.  Why would you expect this to be so?

Answer (score 2):

Given the behaviour of `product` in the first two cases, you shouldn't really be surprised by its behaviour in the third case. You actually want to `zip` lists 3 and 6:

```
>>> list7 = list(zip(list3Append, list6Append))
[(('In1', 'Ta1'), ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9])),
 (('In1', 'Ta2'), ([1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12])),
 (('In2', 'Ta1'), ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])),
 (('In2', 'Ta2'), ([4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12]))]
```

Moreover, there is no need to declare loop variables beforehand:

```
list1, list2  = ('In1', 'In2'), ('Ta1', 'Ta2')

list3Append = []
for list3 in itertools.product(list1, list2, repeat=1):
    list3Append.append(list3)
# Or simply:
list3Append = list(itertools.product(list1, list2))
```